# Windows phone difference between mouse event and multi touch

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, xna-4.0

I don't have a windows phone so all I know is the windows phone simulator.

I've been using the mouse to click on screen and works fine... 
but will this still work on the real device?

I mean is there a difference on using multi touch or mouse events
for a simple click in the real device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. If the gesture works on the emulator, the same gesture will work on the phone. That being said, I would highly recommend testing the app on the phone anyway.

Comment: I would test it if I could, So you are saying that using mouse events also works on multi touch screen on WP 7?

Comment: Yes, testing tapping and navigating around the app on the emulator will be fine, but this won't let you see what performance is like on a real device. (It's typically much worse than the emulator.)